# Combining two stl files into one object

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, meshlab

I have an stl file of a cylinder and an stl file of a sphere.
I want to use these two stl files to produce a third that is an stl of a ball with a hole through it.

The cylinder (the hole) has the same length as the diameter of the sphere.

So how do I use meshlab to 'reduce' the ball by the contents of the cylinder and produce a new object?

Answer (score 0):

MeshLab has some boolean operations under the "CSG Operation" filter, however this resamples the meshes, which is probably not what you want. It is also prone to crashing.

Suggested alternatives are:

- atomiccompiler.com : web site that can do (among other things) boolean operations on uploaded STLs, and provide a new STL for download. No need to install software. Downside is it limits file sizes.
- Blender : can handle complex boolean operations fairly reliably, and also handles colors correctly. Steep learning curve for new users.
- OpenSCAD : nice programmatic CAD tool but sometimes crashes when given large STLs.